# Haskell Read something from a String and return type and rest of the String

Tags: haskell

So I know I can parse something from a string `s` like this:

```
read s :: Int
```

But this only works if the string is the entire type you are reading. I actually want to be able to read a stream of the same type and create a list however I couldn't find anything of the type

```
Read a => String -> (a, String)
```

Or something of that sort. Basically I want to be able to something like `readSeries "5 6 7"` and get `[5, 6, 7]` and I thought the easiest would be if I can get something to return the rest of the string too.

Comment: Note that you can use [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Read+a+%3D%3E+String+-%3E+%28a%2C+String%29) to search for that type. The first answer is what you want, even if it hides its type under the `ReadS` alias.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `reads` for that.

```
> (reads :: ReadS Int) "5 6 7"
[(5," 6 7")]
```

You can also combine `words` and `read`, but it will be fragile -- e.g. if any value has a space in it, this will break in fun ways.

```
Text.Read> mapM readMaybe (words "5 6 7") :: Maybe [Int] -- safer
Just [5,6,7]
> map read (words "5 6 7") :: [Int] -- more convenient
[5,6,7]
```

An example of these last ones breaking due to spaces in values, while the `reads` solution works properly:

```
> (reads :: ReadS (Maybe Int)) "Just 5 Just 6 Just 7"
[(Just 5," Just 6 Just 7")]
Text.Read> mapM readMaybe (words "Just 5 Just 6 Just 7") :: Maybe [Maybe Int]
Nothing
```